# Two functions (Javascript and AJAX) dont work together

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Im trying to send some data to the server through `AJAX` with the value i get from a JS variable.
Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var url;
    function aplicarFoto(_src) {
        url = _src;
        var fotosel = document.getElementById("fotosel");
        fotosel.src = 'fotos/'+_src;
    }

    function guardarCambios() {
        $.post("guardarCambios.php",
              {url: url},
              function(response) {
                  alert(response);
                  if (response == "NoUsuario") {
                      window.location = "../login.php";
                  } else {
                      alert("correcto");
                  }                         
              }
          alert(url);
    }
</script>
```

The idea is update the user picture with the url i get from `aplicarFoto(_src)` with the variable `url` .
The first function (`aplicarFoto(_src)`) alone works correctly, but when i put the another function (`guardarCambios()`), the first function doesnt work, therefore the second neither! I dont know why, but it just happens when using `ajax` functions because i did a test with an `alert(url)` (sunrrounding the rest of code with comments) in the second function and both work correctly!
Some guess? Thank you!

Comment: i guess you need to close your $post section properly." });" just before alert(url);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your script alone has syntax errors.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var url;

function aplicarFoto(_src) {
    url = _src;
    var fotosel = document.getElementById("fotosel");
    fotosel.src = 'fotos/' + _src;

}

function guardarCambios() {
    $.post("guardarCambios.php", {
            url: url
        }, function (response) {
            alert(response);
            if (response == "NoUsuario") {
                window.location = "../login.php";

            } else {
                alert("correcto");
            }
            alert(url);
        }

    );
}
</script>
```

Comment: Ohhhh sorry! :( I didnt notice that! Thank you! :)